# boost - handle end of file error for a serial port (usb cable reconnection)

Tags: c++, boost

I use boost to read/write from a serial port. A device is connected via USB (ttyACM0). My code works but I'm not sure if I correct handle End Of File Error which I get when an usb cable is detached during reading. Opening a serial port looks like this (I put here only the most important part of the code):

```
//this thread tries to open a serial port
if(serialPort_.is_open())
{
   serialPort_.close();
}

try
{
   serialPort_.open(port);
}
catch(std::exception& e)
{
   //some code
   continue;
}

if (serialPort_.is_open())
{
   serialPort_.set_option(/*baud rate etc. */);
   startRead();
}
else
{
   //some code
   continue;
}

/////Handling end of file (or open other port), works but I'm not sure if it is correct
if(ioServiceRun)
{
   ioServiceThread_.interrupt();

   if(ioServiceThread_.joinable())
   {
      ioServiceThread_.join();
      ioServiceRun = false;
      ioService_.reset();
   }
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

if(!ioServiceRun)
{
   try
   {
      ioServiceThread_ = boost::thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &ioService_));
   }
   catch (std::exception&)
   {
      //some code
      continue;
   }
   ioServiceRun = true;
}
```

Here are reading functions:

```
void startRead()
{
   serialPort_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(readSerialPortData_),
   boost::bind(&SerialPortAccess::readComplete, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}

void readComplete(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytesTransferred)
{
   if (!error)
   {
      if (bytesTransferred > 0 && !readSerialPortData_.empty())
      {
         //handle data
      }
      startRead();
   }
   else
   {
      if(error == boost::asio::error::eof)
      {
         //async try to open serial port (someone may connect usb cable again), notify other thread (code presented above)
         open("/dev/ttyACM0");
      }
      else
      {
         close();
      }
   }
}
```

Is the implementation correct ?

Comment: What do your `open` and `close` functions do?